# Pure JavaScript!! onclick affects only to same level classname

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
function toggleClass(element, className){
  if (!element || !className){
    return;
  }

  var classString = element.className, nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
  if (nameIndex == -1) {
    classString += ' ' + className;
  }
  else {
    classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex+className.length);
  }
  element.className = classString;
}

function dropDown() {
  toggleClass(document.getElementById('overlay'), 'overlayOpen');
}
```

```css
.overlayOpen {
  opacity:1 !important;
  height: 200px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
#overlay {
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 800px;
  opacity:0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id='1' onclick='dropDown()'>Some text</li>
  <li id='overlay'>Some content to be shown on click</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li id='2' onclick='dropDown()'>Some text</li>
  <li id='overlay'>Some content to be shown on click</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li id='3' onclick='dropDown()'>Some text</li>
  <li id='overlay'>Some content to be shown on click</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li id='4' onclick='dropDown()'>Some text</li>
  <li id='overlay'>Some content to be shown on click</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that it always opens the first drop-down no matter if you clicking on first second third or fourth. I'm new with JS so would be cool to know how every click can open the element next to it and not always first one.

Ohh and please don't suggest any Jquery solutions.

Thanks for help

Comment: No duplicate IDs! 1 **Unique** ID per element!

Comment: `document.getElementById('overlay')` will always return the first element with the ID `overlay`. Give each element a unique ID and then see if you can find a solution to your problem.

Comment: First, HTML attributes should be wrapped in double quotes `"`, and re-using the same ID is not something that's considered a good practice (it should be unique per page, no wonder your JS doesn't know which one to look at, if there are "multiple unique" ids). You should change `id='overlay'` to `class="overlay"` and in your CSS update `#overlay` to `.overlay`, and adjust your JS according to this

Comment: @AlexSzabó Do you have a reference for HTML requiring double quotes? As far as I can tell, both double and single quotes are equally fine.

Comment: @smarx You are right, they are interchangeable, I've taken this as a base https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=HTML_Quotation_Marks#HTML_Quotation_Marks

Comment: @AlexSzabó: Double quotes, single quotes, or indeed no quotes at all (for values that don't have certain characters), all are fine: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `this` on `dropDown` parameters, and update the `dropDown` function.

```js
function toggleClass(element, className){
  if (!element || !className){
    return;
  }

  

  var classString = element.className, nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
  if (nameIndex == -1) {
    classString += ' ' + className;
  }
  else {
    classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex+className.length);
  }
  element.className = classString;
}

function dropDown(el) {
 var el2 = el.nextElementSibling;
  toggleClass(el2, 'overlayOpen');
}
```

```css
.overlayOpen {
  opacity:1 !important;
  height: 200px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
#overlay {
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 800px;
  opacity:0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id='1' onclick='dropDown(this)'>Some text</li>
  <li id='overlay'>Some content to be shown on click</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li id='2' onclick='dropDown(this)'>Some text</li>
  <li id='overlay'>Some content to be shown on click</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li id='3' onclick='dropDown(this)'>Some text</li>
  <li id='overlay'>Some content to be shown on click</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li id='4' onclick='dropDown(this)'>Some text</li>
  <li id='overlay'>Some content to be shown on click</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the class is meant to be added to the second `<li>` in the `<ul>`, not the one that's clicked.

Comment: @smarx Yes, exact!

Comment: T.J Crowder,  el.nextElementSibling works for Francois Rousselet's code. Thank you All .

Comment: @FrançoisRousselet: The `nextElementSibling` belongs in `dropDown`, not `toggleClass`.